# How many knights can be placed on an n-by-m chessboard?

Tags: algorithms

I have a task, and its essence is as follows: how many knights on an $n \times m$ board can be set so that they do not attack each other. I am wondering if there is any mathematical solution to this problem, except for the algorithmic one.

Comment: Sounds like a question for [math.se]. If you ask it there, please close it here, to prevent duplicates.

Answer (score 2):

For an 8*8 chess board,

1. You need to observe that when 2 knights beat one another they lie on cells of different colors.
2. We can generate a solution by placing 32 knights in the 32 white cells so that no 2 knights beat each other.
3. To prove that this is the optimal solution, we can group our rows into pairs (1,3),(2,4),(5,7),(6,8). Let us consider the row pair (1,3). Consider the pairs of cells (R1C1,R3C2) and (R1C2,R3C1). We can see that we can place only 1 knight in the cell pair (R1C1,R3C2) and only 1 knight in the cell pair (R1C2,R3C1). Continuing this idea, we can show that we cannot place more than 32 knights in an 8X8 chessboard.
4. We already have an arrangement of 32 knights from point 2. Hence, the solution described in point 2 is optimal.

Expanding the above idea, below are the maximum no. of knights that can places such that no 2 beat each other on any N*M chessboard.

1. If *both N and M are odd*, then the solution is **((N*M)+1)/2**
2. If *either N or M is even*, then the solution is **(N*M)/2**

Comment: What happens when one of $N$ and $M$ is 1 or 2? 6 knights can be put on 2*5 chessboard.

Comment: Apologies, I missed those cases. I assumed both N and M to be large.

Answer (score 1):

A knight on a black field cannot take a knight on a white field, and vice  versa. So we can just put all the knights on the same colour. Calculate the number of white and black squares and take the maximum. This gives a lower bound. For an n*m rectangle where either n or m are even, the number is (n * m) / 2. If n and m are both odd, then we have (n * m + 1) / 2 fields of one colour and (n * m - 1) / 2 fields of the other colour, so we can place (n * m + 1) / 2 knights.

To prove that this is optimal you need to prove that any k knights on one color will threaten k or more squares of the other colour. That might not be true for more interesting shapes then rectangles.

For example take a board of n x n squares rotated by 45 degrees, n odd, which would have more squares of one color, and another which has more squares of the other color, then join them at a corner.

We can fit more knights on narrow rectangles by putting knights on different colour squares. You can put n knights on a 1 by n board. And for a 2 by n board, if n = 4k+2 then we can put k+1 blocks of 4 knights in a square separated by k empty 2x2 squares. That's (n * m + 4) / 2 knights. For n = 4k+1 or 4k+3 we can also fill (n * m + 2) / 2 squares. That's either two more or one more knights than the general formula leads us to expect.

Example: 16 knights instead of 14 or 15, 14 knights instead of 13:

```
XX__XX__XX__XX  
XX__XX__XX__XX

XX__XX__XX__XX_  
XX__XX__XX__XX_

XX__XX__XX__X  
XX__XX__XX__X
```

Answer (score -2):

```
if(r==1 || c==1)
        ans=r*c;
    else if(r==2 || c==2)
        ans= 4*int(max(r,c)/4)+2*min(2,max(r,c)%4);
    else if(r%2==1 && c%2==1)
        ans=((r*c)+1)/2;
    else
        ans=(r*c)/2;
```

Note: Here r is row and c is column.

Comment: How does this help understanding the problem?